# Protractor clicking on the link, but element is not visible?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

Hu guys,

I have a problem when I want to click on a link that is in list on html page. Here is my html:

```
<h3>{{snapshot.contractKey}}&nbsp;</h3>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li><a id="documentLink" href="" ng-click="checkAndRedirect('/document1/')"><span translate="contractDetail.document1"> Document</span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-file-text"></i></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a id="detailsLink" href="" ng-click="checkAndRedirect('/document2/')"> <span translate="contractDetail.document2"> Details</span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i></a></li>
                <li><a id="revisionsLink" href="" ng-click="checkAndRedirect('/document3/')"> <span translate="contractDetail.document3"> Revisions </span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></a></li>
                <li><a id="auditTrailLink" href="" ng-click="checkAndRedirect('/document4/')"> <span translate="contractDetail.document4"> Audit Trail</span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-tasks"></i></a></li>
                <li><a id="actionHistoryLink" href="" ng-click="checkAndRedirect('/document5/')"> <span translate="contractDetail.document5">Action History </span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
```

When I want to click on a link by its ID in protractor test, error is shown **No such element** or **Element is not visible.**

Here is my test line of code:

```
element(by.id('documentLink')).click();
```

Do you know why it is bad solution and what do to?

When I do this:

```
element.all(by.tagName('a')).then(function(results){ 
        expect(results.length).toEqual(5);
  });
```

he returns me that is correct and there are 5 links on page. But when I try to access them by ID, I can not do that?

Comment: Is your link in a dropdown?

Comment: No, it is not. It is tab menu.

Comment: What does give:`expect(element(by.id('documentLink')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);` ?

Comment: It says true. Protractor recognize the link

Comment: Sorry, I found the sollution. It's my mistake. Because my configuration for test is set that protractor opens half of Chrome browser, my tab menu is under a button (because of responsiveness) and that causes that links are invisible on the page. 
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your comment, I suggest you to use the `onPrepare` option in your Protractor config to maximize the browser window before your specs start running:

```
onPrepare: function() {
  browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Comment: I have one more question: 
if I have integration with one other site that is established when I click on button, can I proceed to test some workflow scenario and on that other site, using ids of elements that I get by firebug for example?
Is that a problem, because that is however different site?

Comment: Wow that can be another good question to ask on SO! What do you mean by 'integration'? Is it included in your page, is it a different route, a popup? You should open a new question and give more details about your case ;)

Comment: Yeah, I will do so, and link question to you here :)

Comment: This is link to another question :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805527/is-protractor-testing-possible-when-i-have-integration-with-other-site

Comment: This doesn't work for me, one has to scroll to get to the element I'm interacting with in my case :( It doesn't fit on the screen even when maximized.

Comment: @axk So you need to "tell" Protractor to scroll down. Maybe these answers can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23573893 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/24181048 ;)