# Protractor testing in iframe in other non-Angular application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

My application is integrated with other site. That integration is established by clicking on the button. When I click on the button, pop-up shows with html that comes from another site. I show that content using this by putting URL in iframe. Url is from external site:

```
<iframe class='' ng-src="{{url}}"></iframe>
```

Can I execute my protractor test on elements on that pop-up?

When I try to access to element on pop-up by ID, it says ***No such element found.*** I got IDs of elements by Firebug tool on Firefox. I hit this, and it returns me false:

```
expect(element(by.id('**id of element in pop-up**')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Can someone help me with this? Is it possible to run Protractor tests and on this kind of html?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425909/protractor-testing-angular-app-in-an-iframe) ?

Comment: Yea, but I can not switch to my iframe. When i hit: 
 ptor.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(protractor.By.xpath('//iframe')));

it says me that is not iframe on page.

Comment: I set ID to iframe and try to access by id, but it says: "No such element."

Comment: I can switch to iframe by using tagName, but I still can not access to button on that pop-up

Comment: When you say pop-up, what do you mean? Is it a new window? A simple div which is designed as a pop-up? Can you provide an example in JS-bin or the link itself?

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch context to iframe. You can do that by adding these lines of code:

```
var driver = ptor.driver;
ptor.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(protractor.By.tagName('iframe')));
```

Try to access your elements in pop-up now?

Comment: I switched context of WebDriver to iframe, but I still can not access to element on that html.