# Scroll down to an element with protractor

Tags: javascript, scroll, jasmine, protractor

I have an element on the page that I'm testing that I have to scroll down to be visible. When I execute my test, I get  **Element is not clickable at point (94, 188)** for example.

I tried the following:

```
dvr.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,250);');
```

But it didn't work. Does anyone know how this works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protractor: Scroll down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571852/protractor-scroll-down)

Comment: I've alredy read this one.It didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this is helpful to you:

```
dvr.executeScript('window.scrollTo(94,188);').then(function() {
    element(by.<<here your button locator>>).click();
})
```

your webdriver is unable to read that point (1254,21),the reason is your protractor browser unable to cover the full of page what do you want to test, then we give a command that browser is scroll to that point (1254,21), then perform the click operation

Answer (score 45):

This seems so late to answer you..
But anyways,

The following code helped me to remove the **Element is not clickable** error.

```
var elm = element.all(by.css('.your-css-class')).get(9);
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elm.getWebElement());

elm.click();
```

Basically this allows you scroll into your view..

Comment: worked like a charm for me. In my case, the test would pass in Chrome because it would auto-scroll, but test would fail in Firefox. With scrollIntoView, test passes in both browsers.

Comment: Thank you @Rahul! You saved my day!

Answer (score 11):

The `window.scrollTo(x,x)` solution didn't work for me. Specially when testing against ripple emulator.
I managed to make it work using `scrollIntoView` method.

```
var scrollToScript = 'document.getElementById("ELEMENT ID").scrollIntoView();';

browser.driver.executeScript(scrollToScript).then(function() {
  element(by.id('ELEMENT ID')).click();
  expect(...);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Vertically scroll top-left corner of the given element (y-direction) into viewport.
 * @param scrollToElement element to be scrolled into visible area
 */
function scrollTo(scrollToElement) {
    var wd = browser.driver;
    return scrollToElement.getLocation().then(function (loc) {
        return wd.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,arguments[0]);', loc.y);
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
scrollTo(element(by.css("div.someclass")));
```

Disclaimer: this code is from *sg-protractor-tools*'s [`scroll.js`](https://github.com/SunGard-Labs/sg-protractor-tools/blob/master/lib/scroll.js).
Code is licensed under the MIT license.

Answer (score 2):

I used the link that Bassem suggested and that works. The steps are as follows:

1. We will have to install sg-protractor-tools with the following command (Use Sudo if you do not have admin accesses):

   ```
   npm install --save-dev sg-protractor-tools
   ```
2. The code then would look something like this (I tried this on wikipedia)

   ```
   var sgpt = require('sg-protractor-tools');
   it ('verify that scroll works', function ()
     { 
      browser.get('http://wikipedia.org');                                             
      browser.manage().window().setSize(1000, 1000); 
      sgpt.scroll.scrollTo(element(by.linkText('Terms of Use'))); 
     }
   );
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try using npm module "sg-protractor-tools", working well for me with firefox and chrome drivers,

It's a clean way to do scroll on page elements,
More details here https://www.npmjs.com/package/sg-protractor-tools

Answer (score 1):

**pass the xpath to this method dynamically it will scroll to the element**

---

```
   scrollToElement: function (element) {
        return element.getLocation().then(function (location) {
            return browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(' + location.x + ', ' + location.y + ');');
        });
    },
```