# Protractor: Testing window scroll behavior

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, protractor

I need to test if the window **does not scroll** if overflow: hidden is applied to the body tag.

Unfortunately scrollTo and any jQuery equivalent actually does scroll (or set position) of window even though overflow: hidden is applied.

WebDriverJS/Protractor lacks a "Window().scroll" method.

Is there a way my code can test this?

Another thing I found odd was that window().getPosition() does not seem to pull the same browser window, for in the test below if you try to getPosition using Protractor, the window position is still 0,0 even though you have executed script in the browser.

Related to these two questions:

- [Scroll down to an element with protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023768/scroll-down-to-an-element-with-protractor)
- [Protractor: Scroll down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571852/protractor-scroll-down)

### Protractor Code

Assume below mywebpage could scroll but has overflow: hidden set

```js
describe('My webpage', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.get('https://127.0.0.1/mywebpage');
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1400,800);                  
        browser.driver.manage().window().setPosition(0,0);
    });
  
    it('Scrolling y is disabled', function() {
        var scrollFunction = function() { 
            window.scrollTo(0,55);
        };
        var getOffsetTop = function() { 
            return document.body.scrollTop; 
        };
        browser.executeScript(scrollFunction).then(function (yes) {
            browser.executeScript(getOffsetTop).then(function (newposition) {
                expect(newposition).toBe(0);
            });
        });
    
    });

    it('Scrolling y is disabled looking at Protractor Window', function() {
      var scrollFunction = function() { 
          window.scrollTo(0,55);
      };
      var getOffsetTop = function() { 
          return document.body.scrollTop; 
      };
      browser.executeScript(scrollFunction).then(function (yes) {
          browser.driver.manage().window().getPosition().then(function (newposition) {
              expect(newposition.getY()).toBe(0); // This is falsely true, if your scrolling y is enabled, this still remains position 0 
          });
      });

    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you are asking about, but, what we've done in a similar case was introducing a reusable *custom jasmine matcher* that *checks if an element has a scroll*:

```
toHaveScroll: function() {
    return {
        compare: function(elm) {
            return {
                pass: protractor.promise.all([
                    elm.getSize(),
                    elm.getAttribute("scrollHeight")
                ]).then(helpers.spread(function (size, scrollHeight) {
                    return scrollHeight >= size.height;
                }))
            };
        }
    };
},
```

Usage:

```
expect(elm).toHaveScroll();
```