# Protractor/XPath - Find element that contains a descendant that contains text

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath, protractor

I am seeking some help with XPath selectors. I've learned the basics of XPath but am having trouble combining them to solve this one problem.

So I have a grid in HTML that contains about 30 rows, each row (from left to right) has a checkbox and employee name. Here is a snippet of the composition of the rows:

```
<div class="ui-grid-row ng-scope" data-row-num="21"> //Whole row
  <div role="row" ui-grid-row="row" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <div role="rowheader" id="1746254927-13-urGrid-005-cell"> //This is checkbox
    <div role="gridcell" id="17443224958-13-urGrid-005-cell">
      <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding text-left"> Appleseed, Jonny</div>
```

My goal here is to find: div class="ui-grid-row ng-scope" data-row-num="21"> based on its descendant containing 'Appleseed, Jonny'. From here, I will extract the data-row-num with getAttribute so I can then navigate to the right checkbox.

What I have so far is:

```
 element(by.xpath("//div[@class='ui-grid-row ng-scope') and contains(.//div, 'Appleseed, Jonny')]"));
```

Could someone help point me in the right direction here? I'm not looking for the element that contains this text, but its parent element so I can extract its data-row-num.

Or if I can find the div element that contains 'Appleseed, Jonny' how could I then find its parent element (in this case it isn't the direct parent but 2 elements up)?

Comment: This seem to work (if to remove redundant bracket after `ng-scope`). Can you describe the issue in more details?

Comment: So there are 5 div elements in each 'Row'. The first div contains all divs in the row, the second div contains 2 divs one of which is a checkbox and one is the employee name, the employee name div contains another div that has the employee name text. There are several of these 'Rows' each with different employee names. I want the top div element you see in the snippet based on the employee name. So buried within each div with data-row-num there is another div that contains the employees name, how do i filter the rows to return one that contains a descendant div that contains the employees name

Comment: Thanks for catching the bracket, I removed it but it still isn't working

Comment: That xpath is working on my end. See if it's something else causing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/94k939h6/

Comment: Honestly I just found out it doesnt work unless the row is visible on screen so that could be why it wasn't working. I was able to get it working (when visible) using another XPath a user posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath should work given the HTML provided

```
//div[@class='ui-grid-row ng-scope'][.//div[contains(.,'Appleseed, Jonny')]]
```

It's looking for a `DIV` that contains the classes specified, `[@class='ui-grid-row ng-scope']`, and also has a child `DIV` that contains the desired text, `[.//div[contains(.,'Appleseed, Jonny')]]`.

I prefer to be as specific as (reasonably) possible, e.g. use the tagname instead of `*` and so on.

Since you mentioned you are looking for the checkbox associated with that row, another way to do this is to look for the checkbox directly, relative to the element that contains the desired text.

```
//div[@role='rowheader'][.//div[contains(.,'Appleseed, Jonny')]]
```

Since I'm assuming you will be using this XPath numerous times, I would put it into a function and pass in the desired text, e.g. "Appleseed, Jonny", as a string and build that into the XPath.

Comment: First XPath worked, thanks! However, protractor isnt able to find the element unless its visible, I will have to figure out how to scroll it into view without having it located first.

Comment: @Bluejuice is it off the screen invisible or just not visible/rendered yet? Here's a protractor example of scrolling to an element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023768/scroll-down-to-an-element-with-protractor. If it's not visible yet, you should be able to use WebDriverWait and wait until it's visible, clickable, etc.

Comment: The row doesnt get revealed until you scroll down to it. I know about the some scroll functions in protractor but they all require an element to scroll to. I can't hardcode anything because the number of employees changes depending on the environment thats being tested. I also need to select a total of 2 employees which is making it more difficult

Comment: @Bluejuice You could scroll once, look for your element... if it's not there, scroll/look again... repeat until you find it.

Comment: I was thinking that but im unaware of how to put that in a loop? Its difficult to handle elements not being visible in protractor since expect() statements that fail will fail the whole it() block. Do you know of a way I could loop this?

Comment: @Bluejuice I don't do protractor but I found this answer that looks like what you want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33694410/2386774.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//*[contains(text(), "Appleseed, Jonny")]/parent::div[contains(@class,"ui-grid-row ng-scope")].
```

Basically parent::* helps in fetching parent elements