# How to click on a checkbox using Mocha/Chai/Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, mocha.js, chai

I am having a hard time trying to click on an element that renders in the DOM but for some strange reason it still gives me an error saying:

```
WebDriverError: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (281, 687)
```

A picture of how the elements/fields are looking:

[image: Picture of HTML]

as you can see this is what is being shown in the HTML when running Mocha/Chai/Protractor. I am using the code **(I want to click on the checkbox)**:

```
it('click busniess customer', function (done) {

    browser.driver
        //.then(() => browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", piPage.getBusinessCustomerCB().getWebElement()))
        .then(() => browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id('isBusinessCustomer'))), 10000, "Timed out Email"))
        .then(() => element(by.id('isBusinessCustomer')).click())
        .then(() => done());
});
```

However it still says that the element is not clickable. What is strange though is that if I manually scroll down the page before the click is going to happend then it is clicking without any issues but if the checkbox is in the length same as the picture then it will throw a error saying that the element is not clickable.

My question is how can I be able to click the element without getting an error about the element is not clickable?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the html of the screenshot you posted?

Comment: @DublinDev Just updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are waiting for the element's presence before attempting clicking it. This might cause some problems sometimes, as `presenceOf` doesn't necessarily mean the element is visible.
Try to chain those functions like this:

`wait for presence -> wait for visibility -> scroll down to the element - > click it`

```
it('click busniess customer', function (done) {
    const element = element(by.id('isBusinessCustomer'));

    browser.driver
        .then(() => browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element), 10000, "Timed out Email"))
        .then(() => browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), 10000, "Timed out Email"))
        .then(() => browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', element.getWebElement())
        .then(() => element.click())
        .then(() => done()));
    });
```

Comment: Hi Joaquin!

I just tried your code and it seems like the scrollIntoView is not going down. The element returns a timed out that means it wasn't able to find the element during 10 seconds. I can see that the error is on `EC.visilibityOf` because it gets a timed out from there.

Comment: I tried to uncomment the `visibilityOf` but then I return once again to `WebDriverError: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point` - and you can clearly see the element because it scrolls down exactly the same height as the picture I had in my question.

Comment: maybe try switching the scroll with coordinates to make it more visible? something like: `browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,100);')` ? (whis will scroll down just by 100 pixels)

Comment: I even tried to scroll down manually but it seems then that it doesn't try to click() at all. Like the click() function doesn't have any effect on it. but if I do `browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();"` that works but it isnt a solution I really want because it won't work on other browser and mobile browser on further project I am on :(.

Comment: I have now updated with a HTML screenshot of the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the scroll to view and click solution as specified in [Scroll down to an element with protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023768/scroll-down-to-an-element-with-protractor/38843418). It should work.

Comment: Hmm im not sure how it will work in future tests if I am going to test on mobile devices?