# Protractor-Not able to select item from drop down

Tags: protractor

I am trying to select item from drop down using the code:

```
var assettype= element(by.model("templateIdTracker"));

if (assettype.isDisplayed()) {
    assettype.click();  
}
browser.sleep(1000);

element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'A')).click();
```

I can click the drop down but on trying to select item, it throws error:

> "Failed: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may
>   not be manipulated"

This is the web page code. Please suggest.

```
<div class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset k-state-border-up" data-role="popup" style="position: absolute; font-size: 14px; font-family: "Open Sans Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-stretch: normal; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 20px; width: 243.5px; height: auto; display: block; transform: translateY(0px);">
  <div class="k-list-optionlabel ng-scope"/>
    <div class="k-group-header" style="display:none"/>
      <div class="k-list-scroller" unselectable="on" style="height: auto;">
        <ul class="k-list k-reset" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1"                     aria-hidden="false" aria-live="off" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox">
          <li class="k-item ng-scope k-state-hover" data-offset-index="0" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">A</li>
          <li id="1ebaaa3b-8f44-4873-b478-fea6fd498b83" class="k-item ng-scope k-state-selected k-state-focused" data-offset-index="1" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">B</li>
          <li class="k-item ng-scope" data-offset-index="2" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">C</li>
          <li class="k-item ng-scope" data-offset-index="3" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">D</li>
          <li class="k-item ng-scope" data-offset-index="4" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">E</li>
          <li class="k-item ng-scope" data-offset-index="5" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">F</li>
          <li class="k-item ng-scope" data-offset-index="6" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">G</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The method `isDisplayed()` returns a promise. You need need to resolve it first to get the boolean value.

Comment: It shows 'present' in console but same error message on trying to click 'A'                                                                                                                                                      element((by.model("templateIdTracker"))).isDisplayed().then(function(result) {
     if ( result ) {
      console.log('present');
      element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'A')).click();
     } else {
         console.log('not present');
     }
 });

Answer (score 0):

You could implement helper method to wait for this element to be visible.

```
Helpers.expectVisible = function (elementLocator, elementDescription) {
    var message = null;
    if (elementDescription) {
        message = elementDescription + ' was not visible';
    }
    return browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elementLocator), WAIT_TIMEOUT, message);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try:

`assettype.click();
element(by.linkText("A")).click();`

Comment: Had tried linkText. It throws error                                              No element found using locator: By(link text, A)

Comment: @Puja make sure that You are identifying Drop-down correctly and it displays all the Options under that Drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your browser can't see the element, its probably on the bottom of the screen.
You can use the same solution to any element you cant see.

Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39074330/1431062

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all!
It simply worked by using 'li' instead of 'option'

element(by.cssContainingText('li', 'A')).click();

instead of                                                                                                          element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'A')).click();

```
    assettype= element(by.model("templateIdTracker"));
    assettype.click();
    browser.sleep(1000);

    element(by.cssContainingText('li', 'A')).click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
```