# How to scroll up and down in Protractor

Tags: protractor, scrollbar

I have a scroll bar inside Window. The CSS of my scroll is '.scrollable'. I want to scroll up until the first element and scroll down until the last element multiple times.
I found follow code, but for my specific case (scroll inside the window), it doesn't help me.

```
 browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);').then(function () {
            console.log('++++++SCROLLED Down+++++');
        });
```

So I replaced window by my css of my scroll:

```
 browser.executeScript('.scrollable.scrollTo(0,200);').then(function () {
            browser.executeScript('.scrollable.scrollTo(0,0);').then(function () {
                // ...
            })
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by doing the following: 
 var lastElement = element(by.xpath("myLastElement]"));  
 
 browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', lastElement.getWebElement());  
 browser.sleep(3000);  
 var firstElement = element(by.xpath("myfristelement')]")) browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', firstElement.getWebElement());  
 browser.sleep(3000);

Answer (score 0):

for scrolling up You need to set x and y axis as `(0,0)`. for more details check [Protractor: Scroll down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571852/protractor-scroll-down).